# Xpath code is working in Katalon but doesn't work in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, web, browser

I am using Katalon addon for Chrome which works fine. But I wanted to create small app with Selenium in Java to do simmilar thing. I am having the problem with xpath which is working with Katalon on chrome, but it is not working when I use it in my Java application in Selenium.

This it the xpath from Katalon:

```
xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Incorrect: Type your incorrect message here'])[1]/following::label[1]
```

And this is what I use with Selenium in Java:

```
WebElement el = driver_1.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)=\'Incorrect: Type your incorrect message here\'])[1]/following::label[1]"));
```

It returns:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: Can you copy xpath from browser and paste here?

Answer (score 1):

Special character `\` is being added in your `xPath` I guess it's happened while you copy paste. Please use the below `xPath`,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Incorrect: Type your incorrect message here'])[1]/following::label[1]"));
```

If you still unable to access element then please use some `Explicit` wait statement.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(
            "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Incorrect: Type your incorrect message here'])[1]/following::label[1]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Incorrect: Type your incorrect message here'])[1]/following::label[1]"));
```